# Simple plugin to check folder contents on component update

Tags: php, component, plugin

I'm wanting to make a very simple plugin. All it needs to do is

1. On installation of the plugin, copy a folder to a particular <s>component's</s> library folder.
2. When a particular <s>component</s>  library is updated (which deletes all folders and rebuilds), check for the folder again and copy it if it was removed.

That's it. I'm not sure how to achieve it though, as the documentation is a bit sparse and the Joomla Facebook group just told me to read that same documentation page or buy a book.

Comment: May I ask for what purpose do you need this? Maybe there is a better way than placing files in a 3rd party component.

Comment: The 3rd party component allows you to add functions, which are placed in a specific folder, but when you update the component those folders are wiped and you have to manually reinstall them.

Comment: That must be a very weird component. If not a secret, which component is this?

Comment: Chronoforms and chronoconnectivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the install **script** there for this task in Joomla which can fire on different points of the extension install or uninstall processes, like install, uninstall, preflight, postflight and on update. You can use that script with your extension (plugin, component or module). You can run any kind of functions at the different events.

You have to study the documentation of this here:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

**SHORT NOTES ABOUT PLUGIN INSTALLER SCRIPT**

Of course if you install a plugin or component then you cannot use `mod_` as a prefix for your installer script, that is obvious for someone who is not lazy to study and understand a bit about Joomla. And the question of how to create a plugin installer script had already been answered hundreds of times in the last 10 years. These are couple of things you should keep attention on though when you create a **plugin installer script**.

In your plugin XML manifest file you should give the name of your installer script whatever it will be, so:

```
<!-- Scripts to run on installation -->
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

The script filename could be simply just `script.php` (many give unique names for that though).

On the top of your plugin file you should include some classes (not in the script file!):

```
use Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver; 

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

Your plugin class name is built up like this: `Plg[plugingroupname][pluginname]`, so in this case when you build an `extension plugin` for example: `class PlgExtensionMybrilliantshit extends CMSPlugin`

Then your **InstallerScript** class name should be the same as your plugin class name otherwise the installer script will not run:

So it is like: `class PlgExtensionMybrilliantshitInstallerScript`

And the functions are running with arguments (with a passed PluginAdapter instance), so for example if you want to run your function on `install` event, then your function is going to be like this:

```
public function install($adapter)
    {
        // here the folder checking and copying lines of the function...
        echo "Hey, I'm installed and checked your folders";
    }
```

**IF IT IS NOT ON YOUR EXTENSION** - **PLUGIN EVENT ON OTHER COMPONENT INSTALL**

Extensions are installed using the **Installation Manager** which also has events when your plugin functions could fire, at the time an extension is installed, updated or uninstalled, for acting on these events you can use an extension plugin:

**plg_extension_custom plugin**

Which plugin has to have a function on event for example:

```
public function onExtensionAfterInstall($installer, $eid)
{
}
```

Where $installer is an instance of JInstaller and $eid is the ID of the newly installed component (or other extension).

Similar event **when an extension is updated** and you can act on it with your plugin and for that you create a function like:

```
public function onExtensionAfterUpdate($installer, $eid)
{
    $comp_id = 956; // you define the component id which you want to act upon
    if ($eid === $comp_id)
    {
        // all the things you want to do... for example:
        $src = ""; // you define any folder path here where you want to copy the folder from.
        $dest = ""; // you define the destination folder path where you want to copy to
        if(! JFolder::exists(JPATH_ROOT . "libraries/cegcore2")) // any folder path and folder you want to check the existence of... after it's deleted on update
        {
            JFolder::copy($src, $dest, $path = '', $force = false, $use_streams = false); // you can copy the deleted folder back
        }
    }
}
```

I have not checked or tried the above particular code (it is just a fast example) so it has to be finetuned when you use it but that would be a skeleton of a simple folder checking and copying plugin, after another component is updated for example and your folder had been deleted by that update.

You can study the use of Joomla **JFolder class** more here: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFolder.html

And you can study **Joomla Plugin** creation more here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

**ACTING ON A COMPONENT WHEN IT IS FIRST INSTALLED**

The question has also come up that what if the component is just installed and in that case we do not yet know the component ID and we cannot really use our plugin function the way we used it on the update event. We cannot identify our component yet by ID.

Now in that case we have to use the `$installer` argument of the event function, since via the passed installer object we can get the manifest file of the extension, thus we can get the name of the installed extension right there. So we can ignite our function only if our extension of interest is installed (by name. In this particular case it is: ChronoForms6)

So the function will look like this:

```
public function onExtensionAfterInstall($installer, $eid)
{
    $xmlobj = $installer->getManifest(); // we get the manifest Object as SimpleXMLElement
    $ext_name = (string) $xmlobj->name; // we get the name of the extension just installed
    if ($ext_name === "ChronoForms6")
    {
        // echo 'this is the extension I want to be ignited on';
        // do the folder copying here or anything you would like to
    }        
}
```

Of course you can use this latter method on update event too and that way you do not have to base your plugin event function on extension ID.

Comment: I don't own the component in question though, is that a problem? And the plugin I want to make is for other people to use, not just my own use.

Comment: I do not see it as a problem, until your plugin will work well and not messing up things :). I do not know which component you want to copy a folder into and why, but that’s another question which we could discuss in a separate question.

Comment: That's literally all I want it to do though - copy a folder to a specified location, and keep it there after the specified component updates. No other functionality at all.

Comment: @Healyhatman - i also do not see the valid purpose of copying a folder within another component's folders, maybe the problem you want to solve can be handled other ways too, but if that is your purpose and solution then that is your purpose and solution. In a new, separate question we can discuss that if you would like to,..

Comment: Don't know why it needs to be a separate question when it's the entire question though?

Comment: @Healyhatman - now you only need about ten lines of code and your custom plugin is made. We will not create the full plugin for you here, that’s not why stackexchange is here for.

Comment: The component is chronoforms. You can add functions to it, which are installed as an additional folder in libraries/cegcore2/.../.../views and .../functions. The problem is that when you update chronoforms, the /libraries/cegcore2 folder is deleted and rebuilt, and you have to re-add the function.

Comment: Was just giving you more information you were after, haven't had a chance to try the code yet it's put the kids to bed time.

Comment: @Healyhatman I'm almost certain the behavior you speak of is a Joomla issue that was fixed in 3.9.2. See this Issue Tracker item https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/23303. Update to latest Joomla version (3.9.3 at the moment) and try updating your extension. The files should no longer be deleted.

Comment: My local version is 3.9.3 so either the issue isn't fixed, or Chronoforms has been set up to uninstall and reinstall the library folder for some reason.

Comment: Alrighty Zollie I got it to check for the folder and copy it if it's not there when *any* component is updated, any way to do it only when the specific one we're talking about is updated? Or is it not computationally worth the database call to check the $eid matching the component? And final most imporant piece of the puzzle - can the plugin copy the folder when it's first installed?

Comment: On my localhost though the ID is 10041 and on my live site the ID is 10272

Comment: @Healyhatman - the extension ID of a component will be different on every Joomla site.

Comment: Yep I just told onExtensionAfterInstall to call $this->onextensionafterpodate and it works fine. Just checking if I should bother checking which component is calling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90562/discussion-between-zollie-and-healyhatman).

Comment: I can make the call to read the database using the id and check for the library update that's fine. That last part though and then I can mark this questions as answered - can the plugin run that folder check the first time it's installed or does it not work that way.. edit: I'll try the installer script thing in the module documentation

Comment: @Healyhatman and Zolie - guys don't abuse the commenting system. It's not for extensive discussions. Please move this discussion to the chat and keep talking there. Also do some clearing and remove your comments from this place. Update your main posts (question/answer) with the results of your dialogue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90564/discussion-on-answer-by-zollie-simple-plugin-to-check-folder-contents-on-compone).

Comment: @Zollie: You have already some experience in this site. Please avoid having extensive discussions in the comments section in the future.